# Dict in combobox. How to get value from selected option?

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, combobox

I want to get "value" after selected "key" in combobox. For example, in first combobox I choose "b", in the second one I choose "e" and I want to get result as a sum of these two options ( "7" ). I don't know what should be in place "num1" and "num2" or I need do it in different way?

'''python

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def main():

zestawienie={
"a": "1",
"b": "2",
"c": "3"
}

zestawienie2={
"d": "4",
"e": "5",
"f": "6"
}


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Energy')
root.geometry('500x200')


def add():
    blank.delete(0, tk.END)
    Ans = float(num1) + float(num2)
    blank.insert(0, Ans)

tk.Label(root, text="Rodzaj źródła ciepła",bd=3).grid(column=0,row=0)
number1 = tk.StringVar()
tk.Label(root, text="System przyhotowania ciepłej wody").grid(column=0,row=2)
number2= tk.StringVar()


combo1 = ttk.Combobox(root,values=list(zestawienie.keys()),justify="center",textvariable=number1)
combo1.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event: label_selected.config(text=zestawienie[number1.get()]))
combo1.grid(column=0,row=1)  
combo1.current(0)




combo2 = ttk.Combobox(root,values=list(zestawienie1.keys()),justify="center",textvariable=number2)
combo2.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event: label_selected1.config(text=zestawienie1[number2.get()]))
combo2.grid(column=0,row=3) 
combo2.current(0)

label_selected = tk.Label(root, text="Not Selected")
label_selected.grid(row=0, column=3)

label_selected1 = tk.Label(root, text="Not Selected")
label_selected1.grid(row=0, column=4)


#num1=
#num2=


blank = tk.Entry(root)
ttk.Label(root, text = "The Answer is:").grid(row=4)
blank.grid(row=4, column=1)
tk.Button(root, text='Add', command=add).grid(row=4, column=3)


root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I recommend you to change is the values in your `dict`. Use `int` or `float` instead of `str` since you are going to perform calculations on the values.

```
zestawienie={"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}

zestawienie2={"d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6}
```

Next, you have some errors in your code like using the wrong variable names. I had to fix it to get the GUI working. With those fixed, the question you asked can be solved by below:

```
def add():
    blank.delete(0, tk.END)
    Ans = zestawienie.get(number1.get()) + zestawienie2.get(number2.get())
    blank.insert(0, Ans)
```

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def main():

    zestawienie = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
    zestawienie2 = {"d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6}

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Energy')
    root.geometry('500x200')

    def add():
        blank.delete(0, tk.END)
        Ans = zestawienie.get(number1.get()) + zestawienie2.get(number2.get())
        blank.insert(0, Ans)

    tk.Label(root, text="Rodzaj źródła ciepła",bd=3).grid(column=0,row=0)
    number1 = tk.StringVar()
    tk.Label(root, text="System przyhotowania ciepłej wody").grid(column=0,row=2)
    number2= tk.StringVar()

    combo1 = ttk.Combobox(root,values=list(zestawienie.keys()),justify="center",textvariable=number1)
    combo1.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event: label_selected.config(text=zestawienie[number1.get()]))
    combo1.grid(column=0,row=1)
    combo1.current(0)

    combo2 = ttk.Combobox(root,values=list(zestawienie2.keys()),justify="center",textvariable=number2)
    combo2.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event: label_selected1.config(text=zestawienie2[number2.get()]))
    combo2.grid(column=0,row=3)
    combo2.current(0)

    label_selected = tk.Label(root, text="Not Selected")
    label_selected.grid(row=0, column=3)

    label_selected1 = tk.Label(root, text="Not Selected")
    label_selected1.grid(row=0, column=4)

    blank = tk.Entry(root)
    ttk.Label(root, text = "The Answer is:").grid(row=4)
    blank.grid(row=4, column=1)
    tk.Button(root, text='Add', command=add).grid(row=4, column=3)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```